# creating android application without using android adt plugin

Tags: android, plugins, command-line, adt

Is it possible to create native android application without using ADT plugin. Creating android app using notepad and compiling and building using command line.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the SDK Tools only. Take a look at [Managing Projects from the Command Line](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html).